# Close reason message doesn't fit into balloon

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, ios-app

In some cases close reason message doesn't fit into balloon:

> [image: portrait]

Especially while using iOS multiple apps mode:

> [image: multiapps]

- App Version: 1.6.5.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.5.3.

The preferred size for the popup was being calculated with an invalid width.  Now the width of the banner will be used.  Like most things related to multi-line text, things will get a little wonky on orientation change (landscape to portrait or split view) but I've not got a good fix for that yet.  I'm also now using the same code for iPhone and iPad, so it'll be one less iPad-only problem. :)

Comment: Still getting some layout issues in 1.6.5.3 on iPhone https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvOWR.png (was about to post a new report but I guess this is the same issue?)