# Close reason balloon's size and position should be corrected while switching to Split View mode

Tags: bug, ios-app

[Close reason balloon issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295239/339911) seems fixed now. But need to handle situations when app is going to Split View mode while balloon is opened.

Before Split View mode (looks good):

> [image: before]

After switching to Split View mode (wrong position):

> [image: after]

With more reduced width (not enough height):

> [image: minwidth]

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Sizing is still an issue on iPhone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvOWR.png

Comment: @Cai your image is opened on some Chrome tabs on the pictures :)